# Cambiar entrada char mayúscula a minúscula c++

Tags: c++

tengo mi código de un juego donde es descubrir la palabra. Tengo todo el código terminado, pero quisiera saber como hacer que si por ejemplo meto una letra Mayúscula, se convierta en minúscula.
Ejemplo: "hola" Si meto una letra mayúscula, quiero que se convierta en minúscula, para que coincida con la palabra "hola", ya que "HOLA" no existe.

intente con esto pero no me da:

```
void letras(char &letra){
    char word;
    cin>>word;
    if(isupper(word)) {
        islower(word);
    }
        letra = word;

}
```

Comment: Pues no es necesario verificar si es mayúscula, ya que aunque ingreses una letra minúscula y la conviertes a minúscula queda lo mismo, simplemente borra el bloque del `if` y cambia `letra = word;` por `letra = char(tolower(word));`

Comment: Gracias <3 funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas crear una función nueva, menos aún una función como la que redactas, simplemente utiliza [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) de [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype):

```
std::cout << std::tolower('A'); // Muestra: a
```